# Loading Polylines coordinates from database and displaying it in a map

Tags: php, javascript, database, google-maps

First of all, i am a beginner in development with the Google Maps API, and want to know what is the best way to show in a map a route made from a polyline wich takes its coordinates from a table in a mysql database?.

The database has a table named "routes" wich contains the following fields

id
route_type
user_id
title
description

another table, called "route_dots" contains all the coordinates for all the routes, with each route having a different Route ID

id
route_id
lat
lng

in other web sites i reached a solution that i could generate a JSON file with all the information of the route such as the LAT and LNG coordinates, title, description and then let the map read that information for displaying the routes. i did that with a php file  wich i called getjson.php that contains the following code ..

```
<?php
require 'con_mapas.php';
try {
$db = new PDO($dsn, $dbuser, $dbpass);
$db->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
$sth = $db->query("SELECT * FROM spots");
$locations = $sth->fetchAll();

echo json_encode( $locations );

} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

?>
```

the file is working good and generates a JSON with the information taken from the database, but my question is, how can i display in a map all of this information (the route drawed as a polyline, with an infowindow containing the title and description? should be noted that each of these lat/lng coordinates stored in the database has a field called "route_id" which can have the value of A, B or C. I want to do is display in a map different routes, corresponding each to a different "route_id" value.

how this can be done? could you help me with the code?

thanks

Comment: Just curious: where is the *order* of the points in each polyline stored? If the answer is that it's the same as the order of those points in the spots (or route_dots) table, AFAIK the order that results appear out of a query is not guaranteed to be the same as the order of rows in the table. Unless there's something I don't know about MySQL. You might need to add a "route_index" column or something to the route_dots table.

Comment: There is a sample of displaying a polyline at https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/v2tov3?hl=en#overlays. Why don't you try working based on that pattern, and then let us know more specifically where you need help.

Answer (score 0):

You can draw a polyline using a set of lat/lng's.

```
  var flightPlanCoordinates = [
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.772323, -122.214897),
    new google.maps.LatLng(21.291982, -157.821856),
    new google.maps.LatLng(-18.142599, 178.431),
    new google.maps.LatLng(-27.46758, 153.027892)
  ];
  var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: flightPlanCoordinates,
    strokeColor: "#FF0000",
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 2
  });
```

[Example on documentations](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#Polylines)

Comment: what i want to do is to get that set of lat/lng from a mysql database and display them on map as a polyline

Comment: Once you've generated the JSON with all lat/lng, you should construct an array like `flightPlanCoordinates` above and proceed.

Comment: thanks, could you give me an example of how i construct that array? lets supose that the getjson.php is on www.mydomain.com/getjson.php wich contains all the lat/lng taken from the database, specifically what i want to know is how to let the map automatically read that file and place the markers? is that possible?